# ProxyCommand ansible option throwing ssh: illegal option error

Tags: ssh, proxy, ansible

## Context

- **ansible 2.7.6**
- **OpenSSH_7.4**

## Issue

I have a `machine A` that i can access only by a gateway that we call the `machine G` through `ssh`.

The external ip adress of the machine G is `10.X.X.X`.

The internal ip adress of the machine A is `192.168.32.10`.

I want to apply an `ansible` playbook on the remote `machine A` using `ProxyCommand` option through the gateway `machine G`.

Into the `group_vars/all` inventory's vars file inventory, i put the following option according the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-configure-a-jump-host-to-access-servers-that-i-have-no-direct-access-to) :

```
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -q -W %h:%p -p {{ JUMPER_PORT }} root@{{ JUMPER_IP }}"'
```

I execute the following command line to trigger ansible :

```
ansible -i $PWD all \
-m ping \
--extra-vars="JUMPER_IP=10.X.X.X JUMPER_PORT=6666"
```

But the command throw an ssh illegal option error. Here is the output :

```
<---> (255, b'', b'ssh: illegal option -- -
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [- c cipher_spec]
   [-D [bind_address:]port] [- E log_file] [-e escape_char]
   [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
   [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]           
   [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [- p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]           
   [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]          
   [user@]hostname [command]
')

<global> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o 
ControlMaster=auto -o . 
ControlPersist=60s -o 
KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no 
-o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey 
-o PasswordAuthentication=no 
-o ConnectTimeout=10
-o 'ProxyCommand=ssh -q -W %h:%p 
-p 6666 root@10.X.X.X'
-o ControlPath=/Users/me/.ansible/cp/853aabe504 
global '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''

--- | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: illegal option -- 
    -\nusage: ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c 
    cipher_spec]\n           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e 
    escape_char]\n           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i 
    identity_file]\n           [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address] [-l . 
    login_name] [-m mac_spec]\n           [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p 
    port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]\n           [-S ctl_path] [-W 
    host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]\n           [user@]hostname 
    [command]\n",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

It seems like the `-W %h:%p` do not replace the host and the port.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You're following an extremely outdated tutorial.

Recent versions of OpenSSH, including the one you're using, have a very simple syntax for specifying a jump host:

```
ssh -J [jumpuser@]jumphost[:jumpport] destination
```

So you can simply do something like this:

```
ansible_ssh_common_args: "-J root@{{JUMPER_IP}}:{{JUMPER_PORT}}"
```

---

As a matter of best practices, consider using a VPN, or IPv6, or both, to avoid the use of jump hosts wherever possible.

Comment: I get the same behavior with `ansible_ssh_common_args: "-J root@{{JUMPER_IP}}:{{JUMPER_PORT}}"`.

Comment: There's probably something else wrong, but I don't know what other changes you have made.